# Vertically centered images inside card

Tags: html, css, image, semantic-ui

Is there a way how to vertically center images inside Card View, if they are not equal height?

```
<div class="ui three cards">
    <div class="ui card">
        <div class="image">
            <img class="ui image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2438119/demo_products/1/aparat1.jpg">
</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui card">
        <div class="image">
            <img class="ui image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2438119/demo_products/2/aparat2.jpg">
</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui card">
        <div class="image">
            <img class="ui image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2438119/demo_products/3/aparat3.jpg">
</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also used JS to put `div.img` in equal heights. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/herko/93kuum6s/) is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/herko/93kuum6s/).

Comment: Well, I use standard [semanticUI CSS with the Card component](http://semantic-ui.com/views/card.html), without any customizations. Do you want me to post the whole CSS here?

Comment: try adding the line-height attribute to the css, that could make it center.

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7nwfhgbz/) and it looks like I'm getting different results. I am importing the Semantic-UI base css and the Cards css

Comment: can You provide only `ui`,  `card`, `image` and `content` from css... some of them need changes.

Comment: Ok so I put what I have in fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/herko/93kuum6s/) so you can have a look. That is exactly what i have in front of me. I used one script to make `div.img` equal height and all I want is to vertically center the images within this div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this solution because it doesn't involve complicated JS (answered by one of SemanticORG members - Jack Lukic):

### HTML:

```
<div class="ui three cards">
  <div class="ui card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2438119/demo_products/1/aparat1.jpg">        
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui card">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2438119/demo_products/2/aparat2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="ui card">
    <div class="image">
      <img  src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2438119/demo_products/3/aparat3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.ui.card .image {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  padding: 0 1em !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

### JS:

```
equalheight = function(container){
    var currentTallest = 0,
            currentRowStart = 0,
            rowDivs = new Array(),
            $el,
            topPosition = 0;

    $(container).each(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        $($el).height('auto')
        topPostion = $el.position().top;

        if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
            for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
                rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
            }
            rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
            currentRowStart = topPostion;
            currentTallest = $el.height();
            rowDivs.push($el);
        } else {
            rowDivs.push($el);
            currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
        }
        for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    equalheight('.ui.card div.image');
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        equalheight('.ui.card div.image')
    });
});
```

### His full answer with jsfiddle links:

> http://jsfiddle.net/1qaepk4n/
>
> Sizing images in js is a slippery slope
>
> though be careful with that
>
> you also dont have to nest ui image in image
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/gabgwrtt/
>
> And with resize..
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/vgq6vec2/

Answer (score 0):

By Your jsfiddle example i made some changes.

What is changed :

1. from every `img` `class="ui image"` is removed
2. after `equalheight('.ui.card div.image');` I put more `javascript` code

`js` code first find all `divs` whose have in they class `cards`. Then, search for all `img` tags inside that `divs`.

Then calculating `height` of `img` tag and his parent `div`, divided by 2 and subtracted `img` `top` position.

After calculation made, in `img` is putted, added `maring-top:*calculation*px`

There is **[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/93kuum6s/4/)**

This is ok, by my opinion, if You can remove `class` from `img`.

I hope so that is what You need.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at your code, but there is a way to center stuff with translate like this:

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

here us a jsfiddle I made with centering bort horizontal and vertical

http://jsfiddle.net/acmg1h05/1/